# Email services is not working on my liferay 7.3 ga5

Tags: email, liferay, html-email, liferay-7, liferay-7.3

I have the same configure in Liferay 7.0 and is it's working.
but the same configure I have moved on  Liferay 7.3 shows me the below logs and it does not send an email.

```
2021-05-05 06:26:15.292 WARN  [liferay/mail-3][MailMessageListener:135] Email test@liferay.com will be ignored because it is included in mail.send.blacklist
2021-05-05 06:26:15.295 WARN  [liferay/mail-3][MailMessageListener:52] Skipping email because the sender is not specified
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After [LPS-84320](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-84320) Liferay denies sending mail when sender is unconfigured in your installation.

Following default emails are consider as not valid unconfigured emails: `noreply@liferay.com, test@liferay.com, noreply@domain.invalid, and test@domain.invalid`

In order to avoid that warn traces and mail issues, you will have to configure a correct email in your portal-ext.properties:

```
admin.email.from.address=...your admin user email...
announcements.email.to.address=...your no-reply email...
```

For more information, see:

- https://learn.liferay.com/dxp/latest/en/installation-and-upgrades/setting-up-liferay/configuring-mail/configuring-default-email-senders.html
- https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029031591-Configuring-Mail#configuring-default-email-senders
- https://help.liferay.com/hc/es/articles/360034603892-Emails-are-not-sent-and-Email-xxxx-will-be-ignored-because-it-is-included-in-mail-send-blacklist-warning-is-written-to-log-file